# How i can make read doesn't show its value in Shell Scripting?

Tags: bash, shell

Hello guys i'm using ubuntu 11, and I'm doing some shell scripting with it.
the only problem i face it right now is "read" show it value, i don't know how it happening with mE cuz this the 1st. time i use "read" and i can see the value of it !!!!
any way here is my codes:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Which file you want 2 store: "
read fname
echo -n "Do u want 2 delete file $fname in its current location? [Y\N]: "
read ansr

sudo tar -c -v -f The_Store.tar $fname
sudo chmod 700 The_Store.tar

if [ "$ansr" = "Y" ]; then
rm $fname
fi

echo "Congrats, ur file been stored"
```

the value of "fname" shows up after the user answer the Q: Do u want 2 delete file $fname in its current location?. Could any one help mE with this.

All what i want is to keep the value of "fname" hiding ..

Comment: Two solutions doesn't work.  Please let us know the version of your bash, the operation system and version. Do you got any error message by using the -s or the stty version? If so, post them.

Comment: my OS is OSX 10.7, Virtualbox 4.6, Ubuntu with Linux 2.6.38-8-generic-pae.

Answer (score 7):

From the `bash` manpage part about `read`:

> **-s**     Silent mode.  If input is coming from a terminal, characters are not echoed.

Answer (score 4):

In case your shell's `read` buildin does not support `-s` option you can also use `stty` command:

```
echo "Which file you want 2 store: "
stty -echo
read fname
stty echo

echo "Do u want 2 delete file $fname in its current location? [Y\N]: "
stty -echo
read ansr
stty echo
```

Comment: What do you mean by that? Could the shell not find the stty command, was the command found, but didn't recognize its parameters or did it just fail  silently? What's your OS, shell and what terminal are you using?

Comment: my OS is OSX, Virtualbox Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.38-8-generic-pae

Comment: and the shell find the command BUT when i write the file name, I can't c it !! & still $fname appears aftr the Q. !!!

Comment: try putting the `echo` command *after* the first `stty` command